# Close question reasons overflow the box

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

This occurs in FF18,Chrome 24.0.1312.57, and IE8 to a lesser extent.

The reasons in the Close Question box overflow the window and cannot be read. It also makes it difficult to click the vote button.

In FF/Chrome, the following occurs:
[image: Close question box]

In IE8, the box crops directly under the words "General Reference". The vote button is accessible without problem, but the GR reason cannot be seen.

Comment: What's your screen resolution?

Comment: On this machine, 1280x960. This also occurred on my Mac at home. I *believe* that one is set to 1920x1200.

Comment: I'm having the same issue running 1600x900 and 1050x1680 with Chrome 24.0.1312.57.  The easy fix is probably to remove GR :)

Comment: It's happening to me as well at 1600x900 and it wasn't happening before.  I'd guess that it wasn't doing this last week.

Comment: It looks like it's been a few days since I last tried to close/reviewed close votes, but it wasn't like this the previous time I tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silly styling bug in the new popup, sorry about that.

The next build will fix it.

Comment: similar issue in the mod offtopic dialog on SO: http://i.imgur.com/D2Wwkeo.png - just in case your fix doesn't already deal with it